# How to Block Bad User Agents (Malwares) in Wildfly?

Tags: java, ubuntu, wildfly, bots, malware

I am using Wildfly 10.1.0.Final on the Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS Server, I put the SSL from letsencrypt.org running with the H2 (HTTP 2) protocol and Spring Security 4.2.2.RELEASE in Production.

The server is working fine with a very good performance and is not slow but I'm getting many bug reports in the wildfly log of java.net.URISyntaxException (Error 500), from user agents like "Mozilla / 5.0 Jorgee".

I would like to know how I can block these type of bad user agents (malware, bots, etc) and(or) prevent this from happening.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: do you use any reverse proxy like nginx? or is wildfly is directly faced to the web?

Comment: Hi, The Wildfly is directly faced to the web.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem multiple times recently and the requests origin were random (Brazil, Germany, Argentine, US, Ireland...). I'm not sure if there is a way to blacklist these request within WildFly configuration however, you may want to consider to create a custom [Java EE Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html).
The solution to my problem was to get a [WAF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Application_Firewall) in front of the [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) but if you don't have one you may want to add Nginx in front of your Web App and blacklist the user agent "Jorgee" as well as paths such as:

- /2phpmyadmin/
- /admin/phpMyAdmin/
- ...

You can find more info [in this blog post](http://www.skepticism.us/2015/05/new-malware-user-agent-value-jorgee/) by Kurtis Rader.